# Mixing shape layers in Photoshop: get colors to lay over one another

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to get the same effect than this with some shape layers:

[image]

...but I can't seem to find the correct blending mode. Would you know of a way to achieve the same effect mixing those layers, so the "center" (the most overlayed area) gets darker than the rest?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use `Multiply` blending mode and solid (non-transparent) Colors.